# Injecting an incoming packet to a network interface

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I want to be able to simulate an incoming packet on a certain physical network interface.

Specifically, given an array of bytes and an interface name, I want to be able to make that interface think a packet containing those bytes arrived from another interface (most likely on another machine).

I've implemented the code that prepares the packet, but I'm unsure what the next step is.

I should point out that I actually need to feed the interface with my bytes, and not use a workaround that might produce a similar results in other machines (I've seen answers to other questions mentioning the loopback interface and external tools). This code is supposed to simulate traffic on a machine that's expecting to receive traffic from certain sources via specific interfaces. Anything else will be ignored by the machine.

Comment: You can use libpcap to do that for you

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by *'I want to be able to make that interface think a packet containing those bytes arrived from another interface'*? Do you mean you want it to be processed by the kernel with the same rules as if it had arrived on that interface, or something else?

Comment: @Shloim when injecting packets with `libpcap` one injects *egress* packets (i.e. they go out the interface) rather than ingress packets (as far as I recall - that's certainly the only use I've put it to).

Comment: have a look to http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/

Comment: @abligh Yes, exactly. I don't want to just send the packet through the interface, I want to simulate a scenario where the packet arrived to the interface, and the interface then sends it elsewhere (the second step having plenty of solutions, from what I've seen).

Comment: @OznOg I just tried that and it doesn't solve my problem. I suppose the issue is the fact it uses libpcap, which - as abligh said - injects egress packets.

Comment: Can you run your solution inside a VM? if so you could do the packet injection on another VM over the virtual network interface. As far as your primary VM is concerned it would be completely normal traffic

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to stick my neck out and say this is not possible without kernel modifications, and possibly driver modifications. Note that:

- There are plenty of ways of generating *egress* packets through a particular interface, including `libpcap`. But you want to generate *ingress* packets.
- There are plenty of ways of generating ingress packets that are not through a *physical* interface - this is what tap/tun devices are for.

If you modify the kernel to allow direct injection of packets into a device's receive queue, that may have unexpected effects, and is still not going to be an accurate simulation of the packets arriving in hardware (e.g. they will not be constrained to the same MTU etc). Perhaps you can build an iptables extension that fools the kernel into thinking the packet came from a different interface; I'm not sure that will do what you need though.

If all you need is simulation (and you are happy with a complete simulation), build a tap/tun driver, and rename the tap interface to `eth0` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on which network layer you're trying to simulate, there may be a work-around.

I have had success getting ip packets into the ingress queue with an ethernet 'hairpin'. That is, by setting the source and destination MAC address to the local interface, sending the packet results in it first appearing as an egress packet, then being 'hairpinned' and also appearing as an ingress packet.

This at least works under linux using pcapplusplus (libpcap under the hood), with my wireless interface. Your millage may vary.

This will obviously only suit your needs if you're OK with modifying the ethernet header, ie only simulating a higher layer.

Here is a snippet of c++ where I spoof a rst tcp packet for a local socket:

```
        //always use the actual device source MAC, even if we're spoofing the remote rst
        //  this produces a 'hairpin' from the egress to the ingress on the interface so the tcp stack actually processes the packet
        //  required because the tcp stack doesn't process egress packets (at least on a linux wireless interface)
        pcpp::EthLayer eth(localMAC,localMAC);
        pcpp::IPv4Layer ip(remoteIP, localIP);
        pcpp::TcpLayer tcp(remotePort, localPort);
        pcpp::Packet pac(60);

        ip.getIPv4Header()->timeToLive = 255;
        tcp.getTcpHeader()->rstFlag = 1;
        tcp.getTcpHeader()->ackFlag = 1;
        tcp.getTcpHeader()->ackNumber = pcpp::hostToNet32(src.Ack);
        tcp.getTcpHeader()->sequenceNumber = pcpp::hostToNet32(src.Seq);

        pac.addLayer(&eth);
        pac.addLayer(&ip);
        pac.addLayer(&tcp);

        pac.computeCalculateFields();
        dev->sendPacket(&pac);
```

EDIT: the same code works on windows on an ethernet interface. It doesn't seem to do the same 'hairpin' judging from wireshark, but the tcp stack does process the packets.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to create a new dummy network device driver, which will have the same functionality as the loopback interface (i.e. it will be dummy). After that you can wrap up a creation of simple tcp packet and specify in the source and destination addresses the addresses of the two network devices.

It sounds a little hard but it's worth trying - you'll learn a lot for the networking and tcp/ip stack in linux.